# Azure Maps - event when completed loading of a datasource

Tags: azure-maps

In my Azure Map (JS), I have the following code that displays various pins on the map.  As the datasource changes, I clear the last set of Sources and add a new array of Sources.

```
datasource.clear();
datasource.add(sourceData);
```

After the .add call, there is a time delay before all the new pins are displayed.  How can I detect when this operation is complete?  Is there an event that exposes this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the clear and the add functions are called, they each causes a rerender of the map to occur. Since these two function calls are one after the other, this can cause the delay you are seeing. The Azure Maps team added another function which overwrites the data in the data source and only does one rerender. Uses the data sources `setShapes` function instead.

```
datasource.setShapes(sourceData);
```

Documentation for this function can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/azure-maps-control/atlas.source.datasource?view=azure-maps-typescript-latest#setshapes-featurecollection---array-feature-atlas-data-geometry--any----atlas-data-geometry---shape--

Comment: That made a big difference.  Thanks.  Might be worth a blog post to explain that function :) !  Having an event when the datasource is completely rendered (each time the map is changing and finishes all changes), would really be helpful.  Bc then I could disable certain functionality until things have settled down.

Comment: I'll add a tip to this document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-maps/create-data-source-web-sdk (ETA will be a day or two)

Comment: As for an event for when the data source has been completely rendered. I believe their is an event that fires, but it doesn't tell us which data source has rendered, only that a render has occurred.

Comment: What is the event?  I was looking through all the events exposed by EventManager and it's not clear (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/azure-maps-control/atlas.eventmanager?view=azure-maps-typescript-latest).  There is dataadded and dataremoved, but those don't sound like what I am looking for.

Comment: There is a `render` event that fires whenever the map style or position changes or any data in a data source has been rendered. This event doesn't provide any details on what triggered the event currently. A [MapEvent object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/azure-maps-control/atlas.mapevent?view=azure-maps-typescript-latest) is returned when this fires.